# php file_get_contents not working properly when using array as parameter

Tags: php

having some trouble on `file_get_contents`, here's my code:

```
<?
 $dir = $_GET['dir'];       
 //$dir = '/misc/test/';
 $ext = '*.jpg';
 $files = glob($dir.$ext, GLOB_BRACE);
 natsort($files);
 if (isset($_REQUEST['streamimage'])){
  $num = $_REQUEST['num'];
  $getimg = file_get_contents($files[$num]);
  header("Cache-Control: max-age=0, must-revalidate");
  header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
  echo $getimg;
  return;
 }
?>
```

when i get the `$dir` value from query string it does not print the image, but when i hard coded the `$dir` value all works well.

on the first call im using this to define the image `path/dir` `stream.php?dir=/misc/test/`. Then to update the image `stream.php?streamimage&num=0`.

Any feedback would be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What is the final String of `$dir.$ext` in both the cases ?

Comment: /misc/test/*.jpg I'm totally lost how to solve this problem :(

Comment: Both the cases have same text ? `/misc/test/*.jpg` ?

Comment: @AlokPatel yes sir, same text on both cases.

Comment: the glob() is working properly because on both cases the array $files are not returning empty meaning it was able to read the files.

Comment: Do you get the correct value of `$num` in both the cases ?

Comment: @AlokPatel yes sir, $num always have the correct value.

Comment: @PolanSantiago actually your code seems to be fine maybe there is a problem in the URL Encoding, try sending `stream.php?dir=%2Fmisc%2Ftest%2F` instead of `stream.php?dir=/misc/test/`

Comment: thanks for the feedback's, i have already fixed by changing the code structure and used NodeJS.